# Add the value to a list in corresponding to a number of times that show in another list

Tags: python, for-loop

How to simplify and automate the following syntax so that i can achieve:

Assumptions:

1. lenght of x and y will alway be the same
2. the number of value in x and y will change

Objective:

1. print the value in y according to the corresponding number of time that show in x

Expected Output>>> ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']

```
v = len(x)
x = [2, 3, 1]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
z = []

for i in range(x[0]):
    z.append(y[0])
for i in range(x[1]):
    z.append(y[1])
for i in range(x[2]):
    z.append(y[2])
```

#if there there is forth value being added in both x and y, then it should repeat the step above#

```
print(z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested loop to do this:

```
x = [2, 3, 1]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
z = []
v = len(x)

for i in range(v):
    for j in range(x[i]):
        z.append(y[i])
print(z)
```

Comment: @DreamyDeerz Please mark the answer as ```Accepted``` if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at using `zip()` function

```
z = []
for amount, item in zip(x, y):
  for _ in range(amount):
    z.append(item)
```

Or, shorter

```
z = []
for amount, item in zip(x, y):
  z.extend(item for _ in range(amount))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just letting another possible solution that works.

```
x = [2, 3, 1]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
z = []

for idx in range(len(x)):
    z += list(y[idx] * x[idx])

print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [2, 3, 1]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
z = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    z.extend([y[i]] * x[i])
        
print(z)
```

Gives output

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine.

```
x = [2, 3, 1]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
z = []
        
for i in x:
    for o in range(i):
        z.append(y[x.index(i)])
        
 print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

One with [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
z = list(chain(*map(repeat, y, x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYuxDsIwDAV3f8XbkiAv0IWFL0EdQhXUSE1iuR7a/nygsJx0J53sNrc63EV7f2sryJbUWltW5CJNDdMcc2VokhSNaMMDzxtjYFxH2k9z0THc68TkRqLjG5e8mv@t/lKi@P/O2BlbCIFINFfzR@j9Aw)